# fill up values using vlookup vba code in multiple rows and colums

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

[image]
[image]

i am trying to populate 4 coulms and 130 rows from b2:b130 in display sheet using vlookup from bills sheet using rowid i created.

my data as in attached image.if anyone can help me with this that will be great.

Comment: Are there `ROWID` numbers consecutive? Is there any restriction regarding the values to be copied? I mean, if target cell is not empty or similar... Even if they are empty, are there on the sheet to be filled already existing values, which should be kept?

Comment: row id numbers are not consective

Comment: From what I can see in your picture, they are. Meaning that the picture is not the most appropriate to make us better understand which the most efficient solution could be...

Comment: You did not say anything about existence of any restriction (empty values or something else...).

Comment: "b2:b130" looks to be "B5:B135"... Is it correct?

Comment: You could use VLOOKUP combined with MATCH (to find column header +1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how small scale this is and where you said you are just a starter with vba, I kept it simple(ish) while getting the desired result.

Commented for understanding.

```
Option Explicit

Sub populateData()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsDisp As Worksheet: Set wsDisp = wb.Worksheets("Display")
    Dim wsBill As Worksheet: Set wsBill = wb.Worksheets("Bills")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    LastRow = wsDisp.Cells(wsDisp.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row                                                            ' finds the last row in column B of the "Display" worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next                                                                                                    ' bypasses errors such as unmatched values
    For i = 1 To LastRow                                                                                                    ' loop until the last row containing data
        wsDisp.Cells(i, 5).Value = wsBill.Cells(Application.Match(wsDisp.Cells(i, 20).Value, wsBill.Range("W:W"), 0), 24)   ' populates "GIDC Gas Paid" row in "Display" worksheet
        wsDisp.Cells(i, 7).Value = wsBill.Cells(Application.Match(wsDisp.Cells(i, 20).Value, wsBill.Range("W:W"), 0), 25)   ' populates "GST-GIDC Gas Paid" row in "Display" worksheet
        wsDisp.Cells(i, 9).Value = wsBill.Cells(Application.Match(wsDisp.Cells(i, 20).Value, wsBill.Range("W:W"), 0), 26)   ' populates "GIDC Booking Paid" row in "Display" worksheet
        wsDisp.Cells(i, 11).Value = wsBill.Cells(Application.Match(wsDisp.Cells(i, 20).Value, wsBill.Range("W:W"), 0), 27)  ' populates "GST-GIDC Booking Paid" row in "Display" worksheet
    Next i                                                                                                                  ' iterates to the next number in the loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the next code, please. It should be very fast and does not increase the workbook size like in case of formulas:

```
Sub copyRangeForSpecRows()
 Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, shS As Worksheet, shD As Worksheet, El As Variant
 Dim arrEX As Variant, arrGY As Variant, arrIZ As Variant, arrKAA As Variant
 Dim pasteRow As Long, lastCopyRow As Long, arrRows As Variant, i As Long, k As Long
 
 Set shS = Sheets("Bills") 'use here your sheet to copy from
 Set shD = Sheets("Display")
 
 firstRow = 5: lastRow = 130
 pasteRow = CLng(shD.Range("T" & firstRow).Value)
 lastCopyRow = CLng(shD.Range("T" & firstRow + lastRow).Value)
 
 ReDim arrEX(1 To lastRow, 1 To 1): ReDim arrGY(1 To lastRow, 1 To 1)
 ReDim arrIZ(1 To lastRow, 1 To 1): ReDim arrKAA(1 To lastRow, 1 To 1)
 arrRows = shD.Range(shD.cells(firstRow, "T"), shD.cells(lastRow + firstRow - 1, "T")).Value
 
 For i = pasteRow To lastCopyRow
    For Each El In arrRows
        If i = CLng(El) Then
            k = k + 1
            arrEX(k, 1) = shS.Range("X" & i).Value
            arrGY(k, 1) = shS.Range("Y" & i).Value
            arrIZ(k, 1) = shS.Range("Z" & i).Value
            arrKAA(k, 1) = shS.Range("AA" & i).Value
        End If
    Next
 Next i
 
 shD.Range("E5:E" & 4 + lastRow).Value = arrEX
 shD.Range("G5:G" & 4 + lastRow).Value = arrGY
 shD.Range("I5:I" & 4 + lastRow).Value = arrIZ
 shD.Range("K5:K" & 4 + lastRow).Value = arrKAA
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: the array version :) I kept mine simple due to level of vba knowledge but this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: @rohail nisar: Which 'above' error? What error on which line?

Comment: @rohail nisar If you tried editing my code to put there something, I rejected the editing. Answering by editing the answer is not allowed. Please describe here the problem you face. The code has been tested and it is functional. I asked you about the range to be processed, but you did not answer anything. If, for instance you would have less rows number then 135, then the source last row could not be correctly defined. This is what I try imagining without knowing what error and on what line the code shows... Not bad to share a picture of bills sheet showing all the range. Especially the bottom

Answer (score -1):

You should use index and Match function instead of Vlookup and if you want hard code then i will suggest you that go from row 1 to lastrow and check if both Sr.No and RowId match then take that data into an array and at the last paste the array data in Display Sheet.

Comment: This is more of a comment then an answer MD

Comment: I know it's not an answer ..But Stack overflow show me something when i cross 100/150 character..So i put it as an answer..Thanks for your down vote and explanation.